# OPcache doesn't cache anything

Tags: php, centos, fastcgi, opcache

I have VPS with nginx+php-fpm installed and OpenCart 2 CMS.
php 7.3

I have 0 cached scripts and 0 cached keys.
OPcache doesn't cache anything, I tried everything but it is still doesn't work

My output from phpinfo():

```
Zend OPcache
Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Enabled
SHM Cache   Enabled
File Cache  Disabled
Startup OK
Shared memory model mmap
Cache hits  0
Cache misses    0
Used memory 8770936
Free memory 125446792
Wasted memory   0
Interned Strings Used memory    413728
Interned Strings Free memory    5877304
Cached scripts  0
Cached keys 0
Max keys    7963
OOM restarts    0
Hash keys restarts  0
Manual restarts 0
```

My opcache config:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename  /etc/php.d/opcache*.blacklist   /etc/php.d/opcache*.blacklist
opcache.consistency_checks  0   0
opcache.dups_fix    Off Off
opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off Off
opcache.error_log   /tmp/opcache    /tmp/opcache
opcache.file_cache  no value    no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks   1   1
opcache.file_cache_only 0   0
opcache.file_update_protection  2   2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180 180
opcache.huge_code_pages Off Off
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 8   8
opcache.lockfile_path   /tmp    /tmp
opcache.log_verbosity_level 1   1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   4000    4000
opcache.max_file_size   0   0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5   5
opcache.memory_consumption  128 128
opcache.opt_debug_level 0   0
opcache.optimization_level  0x7FFEBFFF  0x7FFEBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value    no value
opcache.protect_memory  0   0
opcache.restrict_api    no value    no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
opcache.revalidate_path Off Off
opcache.save_comments   1   1
opcache.use_cwd On  On
opcache.validate_permission Off Off
opcache.validate_root   Off Off
opcache.validate_timestamps On  On
```

/etc/php.d/opcache*.blacklist is clear

Comment: Did you figure out what is the issue? I see same in my case. The memory seems to change but the cache hits and miss are zero.

Comment: The problem was in ioncube loader. It has a bug in 10.3.8 version. Check your version and go to 10.3.7 or 10.3.9

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in ioncube loader. It has a bug in 10.3.8 version.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to check IonCube version?

Comment: use 'php -v' in CLI